# Is there a way to preserve local data on "flutter install"

Tags: android, flutter, installation

**flutter install** does always delete app data on Android even when reinstalling same apk, at least that's what I'm seeing.
Is there a way to preserve the data during installation?

Comment: Could you please tell what you mean by `preserve local data`, do you mean it deletes the `shared_preferences` values?

Comment: Don't know about those, but it deletes files.